# Why there is need to mention object in friend function?

Tags: c++, class, vector, friend-function

Is it necessary to write an object in friend function to access private members of the class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class project
{
  private:
  vector<int> v1;
  public:
    void addelement(int a)
    {
      v1.push_back(a);

    }

    void view()
    {
      for(auto i=v1.begin();i<v1.end();i++)
      {
        cout<<*i<<endl;
      }
    }

    friend void modify(int,int,project);

};

void modify(int data,int index,project p)//is it necessary here to make an object of class .
    {
      p.v1[index]=data;//As here without "p." it shows errors,it says use 
                        //of unidentified identifier v1
    }

int main()
{
  project p1;
  p1.addelement(7);
  p1.addelement(91);
  modify(24,0,p1);
  modify(22,3,p1);
  p1.view();
}
```

I wonder if a friend function is a friend of a class and it can access private members of class on its own then why there is need to mention object of that class?

Comment: By the way, you're passing `project p` by value to `modify`, so changes to it aren't reflected in `p1`. You need to pass it by reference (`project& p`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `friend` function is not a member function of that class.

How should `modify(24,0)` know to which instance of `project` you are referring to? As of that, you need to pass the instance of `project` to that `friend` function.

An additional note, `void modify(int data, int index, project p)` creates a copy of `p`, if you want to modify the object you pass to `modify` you need to either write:

```
void modify(int data, int index, project &p) {
  p.v1[index]=data;
}
//...
modify(24,0,p1)
```

or

```
void modify(int data, int index, project *p) {
  p->v1[index]=data;
}
//...
modify(24,0,&p1)
```

Comment: But here it is showing the result correctly , so i think here we does not need any reference to object AND if so in what conditions we need to pass reference of object?Please explain .Thank you!!

Comment: @Gautam "*But here it is showing the result correctly*" where?

Comment: @GautamGoyal I'm pretty sure it does not show the correct result. Furthermore `modify(22,3,p1);` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: you can try running my program

Comment: sorry I checked it again and u were correct it's not modifying the values.Thank u very much!!

Answer (score 4):

Only non-static member functions are called on an object like this:

```
object_arg.name_of_member_function(regular_args);
```

And as such, non-static member functions have access to the `this` pointer that points to the `object_arg`, and implicitly the members of the object pointed by `this`.

All other functions, which consist of static member functions and free functions, including those free functions that are friends of a class such as your `modify`, are called without an object argument like this:

```
name_of_function(regular_args);
```

As such, they have no `this` pointer. If you want to access some object, you have to pass it as a regular argument.

---

P.S. Modifying an argument that was passed by value is mostly useless.